# Registering An application on behalf of an organization to use Graph API

Tags: uwp, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am stuck here. I sign up for an Office 365 Trial. I created few users and meeting rooms as well. I created an ID for myself and I feel its the Admin one `apoorv2020@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com`

[image]

I want to access meeting details, the calendar, schedule a meeting, and get profile pictures using the **Microsoft Graph API**.

I tried creating an Application on the Azure AD provided with my Office 365 Subscription but I started getting Authentication Failure .

> Application '6038996c-9877-489e-a2f5-f78b60d13149' is not supported
> for this API version

From articles [here](https://github.com/simi/omniauth-office365/issues/7), I found out that the Application should be registered [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) (Application Registration Portal).

I tried login using the admin email ID (`apoorv2020@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com`) but it didn't let me login.

Moreover, I have created a personal email ID and I am able to login into the Application Registration Portal and create the Application for accessing my personal details but how to proceed for an organizational setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, there are two endpoints for authentication with Azure AD accounts. We need to use the corresponding endpoint based where the app register.

The first one is register the app from [Azure portal](http://ms.portal.azure.com), and then we can interact with Azure AD via Oauth by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code).

And the other endpoint is resisting the apps from [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), and using the [V2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols).

The major different between original endpoint with V2.0 endpoint is that the V2.0 endpoint supports both Azure AD origination accounts and Microsoft Accounts. And the V2.0 uses `scope` instead of `resource`. More detail about Azure AD V2.0 endpoint, you can refer the document below:

[Sign-in Microsoft Account & Azure AD users in a single app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)

If you only want the apps support for Azure AD account, you can choose the orignal endpoint.

Comment: how to I integrate the app to access my office 365 data? I have mentioned in my question that the App Registration portal is not letting me login using my .onmicrosoft.com account

Comment: You just need to register app on Azure portal and config Microsoft Graph and corresponding permission for that app. Then you can access  the Office 365 data via [Microsoft Graph REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview). What's the endpoint you were integrate? If you register the app on App Registration portal, you should use **V2.0** endpoint. In the authorization URL, there should contains `v2.0` like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Comment: can you come on chat and help me ?

Comment: I have opened a chat, did you receive the notification?

Comment: No I Didn't get it . please paste the link

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154317/room-for-fei-xue-and-apoorv

Comment: @Apoorv I just downloaded the code sample from the link you provided. And it works perfect for me. You may share the code how you modifying or test the sample without any custom code to see whether it works well for you.

Comment: I am unable to login using my .onmicrosoft.com account

Comment: @Xei : I want to access data of an organization.  I am using GRAPH APIs provided in my GRAPH Explorer. I have a problem that I can't login using the onmicrosoft.com account as the API is giving me the error mentioned in the question. It works fine for my personal email ID but again , I cant use the FindMeetingTimes API as it needs a work or school ID. I need help here

Comment: @Apoorv It works for me for the organization account. Is the orignal sample code works for your organization account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154402/discussion-between-apoorv-and-fei-xue).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the differences between Application Registration and Application Authorization.

When you Register your Application (either via the [Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) or through your [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/)), you're simply creating a public record of your Application.

When users/organizations authorize your Application, they're using your `appid` to look up your apps registration to determine if they trust you or not. If they move forward, a record is created in *their* directory noting that they have given authorization to the `appid` from *your* registration.

Behind the scenes, both the Azure Portal and the Application Registration Portal are doing the same thing - creating a publicly accessible App ID that 3rd parties can authorize.

As for accessing data, this is actually entirely separate from the authentication process. Once a user/organization has authenticated and authorized your application, you'll receive a token. You then pass this token when making calls into the Microsoft Graph API. The API will handle the routeing between your calls and the proper tenant for you automatically.

Comment: I want to access data of an organization.  I am using GRAPH APIs provided in my GRAPH Explorer. I have a problem that I can't login using the onmicrosoft.com account as the API is giving me the error mentioned in the question. It works fine for my personal email ID but again , I cant use the FindMeetingTimes API as it needs a work or school ID. I need help here

Comment: When you say "your" Graph Explorer, are you running a local copy or using the one hosted at https://graph.microsoft.io?